# how to set input type to be numberdecimal but also allow a "-"

Tags: android

I have set input type to be numberdecimal but also want to populate the editText with a "-" programmatically. I can add the text but then I am unable to edit the text as it doesn't confirm to the number decimal format. Any idea on how I can say inputtype is numberdecimal but a "-" can be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write your own [KeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html). You could start by [downloading the source](http://source.android.com/) of the [NumberKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/NumberKeyListener.html) and take it from there.

Martin

Comment: Martin, is there a way I can look at the source code without downloading it from the github?

Comment: Well there is the web interface at http://android.git.kernel.org/ - but it does not look very helpful. If at all possible you should try to get the source.

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172242/live-editing-of-users-input/4172392#4172392

Answer (score 39):

I was able to achieve this behavior by setting `digits` xml attribute as follows:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789-"/>
```

Setting it up programatically ([Set EditText Digits Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300490/set-edittext-digits-programatically)):

```
weightInput.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789-"));
```

Answer (score 10):

I managed to do that with:

```
android:inputType="number|numberSigned"    
android:digits="0123456789-"
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a very easy solution:

```
editText.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener(true, true));
```

The first `true` is for whether is signed input, the second `true` is for decimal.
Hope that helps

Comment: Gustavo, bemace, sorry for not being clear. I am talking about the hyphen inbetween numbers. something like 1-800-555555 and not the sign at front of the number.

Answer (score 1):

I am having one solution, which may helps you:

Suppose, You want to enter 2-3 numbers with "-" sign for e.g. 203-304-405.23-232.45,

then Allow user to enter this in EditText without setting any attributes.
and then you can Separate each numbers with "**`split()`**" function , but be sure that there should be any separator sign in between the tokens.

then

```
 String tokens[];
 strInput = edittext1.getText.toString();
 tokens = strInput.split(",");
```

then you can work with each tokens separately as tokens[0], tokens[1],
for example:

```
num1 = tokens[0];
num2 = tokens[1];
```

Hope this helps you.

Enjoy!!

Comment: Thanks Paresh for your insights... You are talking about post processing of the text entered by the user but unfortunately I cannot allow user to enter anything in EditText other than numbers. InputType has to be fixed to decimal :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just created a simple class that allows numbers and hyphen only.

```
private static class myFilter implements InputFilter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                               Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        // Allow digits and hyphen in the input
        String filters = "0123456789-";

        StringBuilder filteredStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
            if (filters.contains(String.valueOf(currentChar))) {
                filteredStringBuilder.append(currentChar);
            }
        }

        return filteredStringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Then in the ActivityClass, to add filter to the EditText:

```
    EditText _eText;
    _eText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    _eText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    _eText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new myFilter()});
```