# Live editing of users input

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

Is it possible to auto insert characters into an `EditText` **as the user inputs data**?

I.e. if the user is entering a long number such as `123456789012`, is it possible for this number to appear as he is typing it in the edit text box, but with a dash every 4th character?

So as you type the number above you would see it being entered in the `EditText` box but would look like this: 1234-5678-9012.

Currently I have an app where you can enter a long number and then press a button and it inserts the dashes for you, but I'm curious if it could be done as you type?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What language? What platform? This, in general, is possible, but the details depend on the language and platform.

Comment: In what technology? E.g. in a web page, an iPhone app, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By tagging android, I think you are discussing about android editText, is so you can do it by listening the TextChangedListener,

EDITED: for backspace

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            int len=0;
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
                String str = editText.getText().toString(); 
                 if(str.length()==4&& len <str.length()){//len check for backspace 
                    editText.append("-");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

             String str = editText.getText().toString(); 
              len = str.length();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {  
            }


        });
```

Comment: Do handle deletions as well - the example given may make it impossible to backspace after typing 4 characters (as deleting the dash will immediately add another back in).

Comment: @Nick , I have edited it for backspace , So its not impossible

Comment: @LabeebP i have tried to use it. but if i press back space . - wont remove also. also once a dash preview in the edittext the cursur will be moved in to forward

Comment: This doesnt add dashes to my edittext. What might be the reason?

Comment: The same that @Figen Güngör for me

Comment: It was appending only for one time how should i append multiple time ?

Comment: I changed my EditText input type to number and I gave digits to "0123456789-" and works perfectly. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

to solve this issue, i write a class "AutoAddTextWatcher" : 
1. Auto insert text into EditText.
2. insert text into EditText at positions you are setted.
3. delete text in EditText at positions you are setted, when text length bigger than 1.

[image]

code snippet :

```
mEditText_birthday.addTextChangedListener(new AutoAddTextWatcher(mEditText_birthday,
            "/",
            new TextWatcher() {},
            4, 6));
```

AutoAddTextWatcher class

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * Created by henry.chuang on 2016/5/12.
 */
public class AutoAddTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private CharSequence mBeforeTextChanged;
    private TextWatcher mTextWatcher;
    private int[] mArray_pos;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private String mAppentText;

    public AutoAddTextWatcher(EditText editText, String appendText, int... position){
        this.mEditText = editText;
        this.mAppentText = appendText;
        this.mArray_pos = position.clone();
    }
    public AutoAddTextWatcher(EditText editText, String appendText, TextWatcher textWatcher, int... position){
        this(editText, appendText, position);
        this.mTextWatcher = textWatcher;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        mBeforeTextChanged = s.toString();

        if(mTextWatcher != null)
            mTextWatcher.beforeTextChanged(s, start, count, after);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mArray_pos.length; i++) {
            if(((mBeforeTextChanged.length() - mAppentText.length() * i) == (mArray_pos[i] - 1) &&
                    (s.length() - mAppentText.length() * i) == mArray_pos[i])){
                mEditText.append(mAppentText);

                break;
            }

            if(((mBeforeTextChanged.length() - mAppentText.length() * i) == mArray_pos[i] &&
                    (s.length() - mAppentText.length() * i) == (mArray_pos[i] + 1))){
                int idx_start = mArray_pos[i] + mAppentText.length() * i;
                int idx_end = Math.min(idx_start + mAppentText.length(), s.length());

                String sub = mEditText.getText().toString().substring(idx_start,  idx_end);

                if(!sub.equals(mAppentText)){
                    mEditText.getText().insert(s.length() - 1, mAppentText);
                }

                break;
            }

            if(mAppentText.length() > 1 &&
                    (mBeforeTextChanged.length() - mAppentText.length() * i) == (mArray_pos[i] + mAppentText.length()) &&
                    (s.length() - mAppentText.length() * i) == (mArray_pos[i] + mAppentText.length() - 1)){
                int idx_start = mArray_pos[i] + mAppentText.length() * i;
                int idx_end = Math.min(idx_start + mAppentText.length(), s.length());

                mEditText.getText().delete(idx_start, idx_end);

                break;
            }

        }

        if(mTextWatcher != null)
            mTextWatcher.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(mTextWatcher != null)
            mTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(s);

    }

}
```

complete demo source :
https://github.com/henrychuangtw/AutoInsertEditText

Comment: Wow dude!  You are a genius!  Thank you so much for this...  I have tried SO MANY solutions, but nothing worked right.  I needed to get it formatted like this: 12-345-67.  Every other solution always had weird things happen when you deleted and then tried to re-enter.  Your solutions works PERFECTLY!   One thing to note though, for your class to work properly, you need to set the input type in the XML file to `android:inputType="phone"`  I tried initially with `android:inputType="number"` and it didn't work.  I checked your github page and saw you used `phone`, and that now works.  Great job!

Comment: Here's my implementation: `enterUserID.addTextChangedListener(new AutoAddTextWatcher(enterUserID,
                "-",
                2, 5));`

Comment: @KevinBright Thanks your encouragement and suggestion, I will try it.

Comment: No, thank you!  I can't believe how hard this is to do properly in Android!

Comment: @HenryChuang: your code was super. previously I implemented my own way by struggling a lot. But your code will help people definitely. If I want to implement copy paste listener to your code, how can we achieve that.

Comment: @sham.y copy paste listener? copy all text on edittext?

Comment: @HenryChuang :  yes, if user copied text and pasted in edit text.

Comment: Hi,Im using this class,But one issue we are observed is when user bring the cursor to back of the string then the position of delimiter is missing as per the requirement.Can you please suggest me is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if(s.length() == 3 && len < s.length()){
        s.append(" - ");
    }

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    len = s.length();
}
```

This will do as well, only this code will insert `" - "` after 3rd character.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used

```
private boolean mInEdit;

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (!mInEdit) {
        mInEdit = true;
        String delimiter = " - ";
        //Remove chars from your delimiter first
        String digits = s.toString().replaceAll("[- ]", "")
                .replaceAll("\\d{4}", "$0" + delimiter);
        //Handle deletion
        int dLength = delimiter.length();
        if (before > count && digits.endsWith(delimiter.charAt(dLength - 1)) {
            digits = digits.substring(0, digits.length() - dLength);
        }
        mCardNumber.setText(digits);
        mCardNumber.setSelection(mCardNumber.length());
        mInEdit = false;
    }
}
```

Here you replace delimiter with what you want to separate digits.

Answer (score 0):

For those still facing trouble  with backspace and multiple hyphens -

```
new TextWatcher() 
{
        boolean hyphenExists;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if (s.length() >= 6 && s.charAt(5) == '-') {
                hyphenExists = true;
            } else {
                hyphenExists = false;
            }

            Log.d("TAG", "beforeTextChanged " + s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Log.d("TAG", "onTextChanged " + s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 5) {
                if (!hyphenExists)
                    s.append('-');
            }
            Log.d("TAG", "afterTextChanged " + s.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with on text changed

in my case, i have to format input like this : xxx xxx-xxxx

i done as given below:

```
etMobileNumber.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {


        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (etMobileNumber.text.length == 3 && count != 0) {
                val text = etMobileNumber.getText().toString() + " "
                etMobileNumber.setText(text)
                etMobileNumber.setSelection(text.length)
            } else if (etMobileNumber.text.length == 7 && count != 0) {
                val text = etMobileNumber.getText().toString() + "-"
                etMobileNumber.setText(text)
                etMobileNumber.setSelection(text.length)
            }
        }
    })
```

and the result is very dynamic on the go while typing.

input- 1234567890
result - 123 456-7890