# EditText input with pattern android

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-edittext, alphanumeric

I am having a EditText in which I have to accept **alphanumeric** input from user which is specific to pattern, and hyphens **'-'** are inserted automatically.

```
"XXX-XXX-XXXX"
```

how to achieve that ? Is there any pattern tool in android ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live editing of users input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172242/live-editing-of-users-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use addTextChangedListener to EditText
Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172242/live-editing-of-users-input/4172392#4172392) , which demonstrate it

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve that with [PatternedTextWatcher](https://github.com/zsavely/PatternedTextWatcher).

Edit:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

// Add text changed listener for automatic dots insertion.
editText.addTextChangedListener(new PatternedTextWatcher("###-###-####"));
```

And in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="1234567890-"/>
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Thanks

Comment: It didn't follow pattern when I tried to delete characters at random intermediate position and then continued to add new characters from that position.