# How can I convert a key code into a char or string?

Tags: android, keycode, typeconverter

How to convert the `keycode` into `char` or `string`??

**Here is the example code:**

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.d("EditText", "It's Working...!" + event.getAction());
    if (event.getAction() == 0) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.editText1:
            Log.d("EditText", "In editText1");
            if (text1.length() == 3)
            {
                text2.setText();
                text2.requestFocus();

            }
            break;

        case R.id.editText2:
            Log.d("EditText", "In editText2");
            if (text2.length() == 0)
                text1.requestFocus();
            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 54):

```
char unicodeChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
```

Comment: Why I got �� when I input keyevent 67 (KEYCODE_DEL) ?

Comment: if you get output like this ��. Filter it this way if (keyCode != 59)

Comment: Note that you don't need to have `KeyEvent` reference to do this. You can convert plain keycode int value by using `KeyCharacterMap`. This is atm basically what `getUnicodeChar()` does.

Comment: getUnicodeChar() now requieres a parameter, that code doesn't work like that

Answer (score 6):

Use [`event.getNumber()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getNumber%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a KeyEvent object you can use this on the keycode :

```
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
     char c = Character.toChars(primaryCode)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tod answer is almost complete, but when you want to settext of an edittext with this eventcode you should to add a little thing:

```
sample_et.setText((char)event.getUnicodeChar()+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a key from one control to another (for instance, from `RecylerView` to `EditText` inside it), you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779000/how-to-send-key-event-to-an-edit-text):

```
editText.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode, 0))
editText.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode, 0))
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this..

```
String s="";

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    EditText t=(EditText)v;
    s=t.getText();  
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use

```
String.fromCharCode();
```

`String.fromCharCode(65,66,67)` returns `ABC`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode .