# How do I convert key code to char or String to show it on TextView

Tags: java, android, keycode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert a key code into a char or string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571081/how-can-i-convert-a-key-code-into-a-char-or-string)

Hey I'm pretty new to Android and unsure how to use getKeyCode. I have this

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch(keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pressed DPAD Right Button",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pressed DPAD Left Button",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
}
```

But I want to change a textview to say what button was pressed. How do I pass the keyCode into the setText function? I already have it all linked up, I just need the keyCode variable to put into

```
txt2.setText(Integer.toString(getKeyCode()));
```

Comment: Have you tried, `KeyEvent.getKeyText(KeyEvent.getKeyCode())`?

Comment: Thanks, got it working :) Quick question though, is there anyway to get it to display the actual name of the key pressed rather than the number assigned to it? @Rossum, that doesnt seem to work, just gives me static/non-static errors.

Comment: @Calender Man: in your code, try `event.getKeyText(event.getKeyCode())`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get an actual name of key you can do something like:

```
int pressedKeyCode = event.getKeyCode();
Object pressedKeyCodeObject = new Integer(pressedKeyCode);
String pressedKeyText = KeyEvent.getKeyText((Integer)pressedKeyCodeObject);
```