# Edit text that only allows a given number of digits, and groups them in pairs of four Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to have an edit text that only allows the user to enter a given number of text, for my case I want 16 digits, and then **group them in pairs of 4**. I have already set the text limit. Currently my code looks like this,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="16">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Code"
        android:inputType="number" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But now my question is how to group them. I want my final output to be something like this **XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-**. Kind a way a product key looks like.

Comment: check this same solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947674/custom-format-edit-text-input-android-to-accept-credit-card-number

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the code below, it works well :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "my_log";
    static final Pattern CODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{0,4})|([0-9]{4}-)+|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{0,4})+");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "input" + s.toString());

                if (s.length() > 0 && !CODE_PATTERN.matcher(s).matches()) {
                    String input = s.toString();
                    String numbersOnly = keepNumbersOnly(input);
                    String code = formatNumbersAsCode(numbersOnly);

                    Log.d(TAG, "numbersOnly" + numbersOnly);
                    Log.d(TAG, "code" + code);

                    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    editText.setText(code);
                    editText.setSelection(code.length());
                    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            private String keepNumbersOnly(CharSequence s) {
                return s.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            }

            private String formatNumbersAsCode(CharSequence s) {
                int groupDigits = 0;
                String tmp = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
                    tmp += s.charAt(i);
                    ++groupDigits;
                    if (groupDigits == 4) {
                        tmp += "-";
                        groupDigits = 0;
                    }
                }
                return tmp;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Add a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText`. Then after every character additon, evaluate the contents and add the dashes as needed. **This is the quicker solution.**
2. Have a look at `EditText` [sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/EditText.java#EditText) (depensing on the API level, it may also be in the [sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) of the super class of `EditText`, `Textview`). Study its `onDraw()` metchod and then implement your own class extending `EditText`, which will draw the text as you want it. **This will take more time, but the `getText()` method will return the raw input, without dashes.**