# How to make {EditText} accept input in format:

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-widget

Car number plate(Registration number) -   `2chars-2digit-2chars-4chars`

I tried this resource with some modification [Custom format edit text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947674/custom-format-edit-text-input-android-to-accept-credit-card-number) , but unfortunately I was unable to delete the Hyphen(-). Whenever there is a Hyphen(-), I could not to delete it. Please help me in finding out the issue.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to delete hyphen because in `ontextchanged`, when you get to the hyphen character position, you are again adding the hyphen.

**You should differentiate if you got to hyphen character by adding the text or by deleting the text.**

If you got to the hyphen position by deleting text, you dont want to add hyphen.

You can check by this code `if(before-count<0){`

Below is your working example

```
     editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                if ((editText.getText().length() + 1 == 3 || editText.getText().length() + 1 == 6 || editText.getText().length() + 1 == 9)) {
                    if(before-count<0){
                        editText.setText(editText.getText() + "-");
                        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                    }
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

}

XML

```
 android:maxLength="13"
```