# "EditText and TextView" formatted with thousands separators (,) in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, separator

I want a thousands separator (,) in EditText when i am typing in editText.
after that,i will do some operation on the number.then show the result in the TextView by thousands separator (,).

this is my code:

```
public class Mainactivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText        edt;
TextView        txt;
Button          btn;

OnClickListener myclick = new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                                // my calculation
                                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(edt.getText().toString());
                                double num2 = num1 + 7;

                                txt.setText("" + num2);

                            }
                        };


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(myclick);

}
```

}

Comment: You could use the answer in 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338445/how-to-automatically-add-thousand-separators-as-number-is-input-in-edittext][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338445/how-to-automatically-add-thousand-separators-as-number-is-input-in-edittext

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
String value=String.format("%,.2f", num );
```

to parse the number to String with a thousands separator and then set the result to the TextView or EditText that you want

For example :

```
txt.setText(String.format("%,.2f", num ));
edt.setText(String.format("%,.2f", num ));
```

Comment: it is good for textView, but for EditText i want to separate as i type the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this code

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            try
            {
                edittext.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                String value = edittext.getText().toString();
                if (value != null && !value.equals(""))
                {
                    String str = edittext.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", "");
                    if (value != null && !value.equals(""))
                        Double.valueOf(str).doubleValue();
                    edittext.setText(getDecimalFormat(str));
                    edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().toString().length());
                }
                edittex.addTextChangedListener(this);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception localException)
            {
                localException.printStackTrace();
                edittext.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }

 private String getDecimalFormat(String value)
{
    StringTokenizer lst = new StringTokenizer(value, ".");
    String str1 = value;
    String str2 = "";
    if (lst.countTokens() > 1)
    {
        str1 = lst.nextToken();
        str2 = lst.nextToken();
    }
    String str3 = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = -1 + str1.length();
    if (str1.charAt( -1 + str1.length()) == '.')
    {
        j--;
        str3 = ".";
    }
    for (int k = j;; k--)
    {
        if (k < 0)
        {
            if (str2.length() > 0)
                str3 = str3 + "." + str2;
            return str3;
        }
        if (i == 3)
        {
            str3 = "," + str3;
            i = 0;
        }
        str3 = str1.charAt(k) + str3;
        i++;
    }
}
```

hope help you