# Add ZERO before "." when user input ".123" or ".1234" in android

Tags: android

I'm working on a program which contains `EditText`.
EditText only accept DecimalNumber .

But in my case :- this `EditText` accepts ".3232"

what I need:- Output should be "0.3232"

How should I achieve this? 
I have used

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
```

Help Needed

Comment: Use Text `addTextChangedListener` to check user input & you can add 0 if it contains `.123` kind of input

Comment: Thanx for help, i will try this and let you know

Answer (score 1):

> But in my case:- this EditText accept ".3232"

its already mean that .3232 == 0.3232

you if you want than you need to do it programmetically

```
String outPut= String.format("%.04f", yourValueFloat .3232);
```

Comment: check my edited answer i was doing a mistake before.

Answer (score 0):

Add [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)  and add this in `afterTextChanged`

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {            
            String value = editText.getText().toString();    

            if (value != null && !value.equals("")) //Additional check 
            {    
                if(value.startsWith(".")){
                    editText.setText("0.");
                }
            }
       }
```

For more info See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34265406/5067493) how I accomplished this for thousand separator. That may be helpful to you.

Comment: @AndrewIndayang Thanks for suggestion but not needed. `afterTextChanged` is called directly when user presses a single character and if that character is DOT then it suddenly sets `0.` if it's not the case of copy and pasting.