# How to automatically add whitespaces in EditText

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, textwatcher

i'm building a simple binary decimal converter and i want the binary strings to be formatted in groups of 4 bits as the user inputs them.

Watching other similar questions led me to manipulate the editable in method "afterTextChanged" but when i run the app and input the 4° digit the app freezes and the RAM monitor starts to go crazy.

Also, my edittext "binary" is set to "numberDecimal". I tried to change that temporarily using something i found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338445/how-to-automatically-add-thousand-separators-as-number-is-input-in-edittext), but i can't seem to get it working.

Here's the code:
(binary is my EditText)

```
binary.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }


       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

      }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(binary.isFocused()){

               temp = binary.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+","");

                  if(temp.length()%4==0){
                     InputFilter[] filters = editable.getFilters(); // save filters
                     editable.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {});     // clear filters
                     editable.insert(editable.length()-1," ");              // edit text
                     editable.setFilters(filters);
                  }
```

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: Woops! i forgot, if in editable.insert() i put a digit, everything works fine. but i need to put a whitespace

Answer (score 1):

I figured out: the adding space was somehow triggering an infinite loop. i managed to resolve that removing the focus before adding the space and re-adding the focus after that. i also made some change to the if condition, so now i can easily delete my binary number without having the cursor stuck.

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        if(binary.isFocused()){

              if(((temp.length()%4 == 0 && temp.length()!=0) && tempSpace.length()<temp.length()) || (tempSpace.isEmpty() && temp.length()%4 == 0)){

                            InputFilter[] filters = editable.getFilters(); // save filters
                            editable.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {});

                           binary.clearFocus();                                // clear filters
                            editable.insert(editable.length()," ");
                            binary.requestFocus();
                                                           // edit text
                            editable.setFilters(filters);
              }

              tempSpace= temp;
```

Where tempSpace is a temporary variable used to compare the length of the edittext before the user pressed the botton.

Thank you anyway for your kind answers :D

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a [`TranformationMethod`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod.html) instead. With `TextWatcher` you have the problem of any changes in `afterTextChanged()` triggering another change, so you may end up looping infinitely if you aren't careful about how you detect when it's apprpriate to respond to the change.

Comment: Hmm...i read the documentation but i've not understood how TrasformationMethod works. i have to create a new class that extends TrasformationMethod?

Comment: @AlessandroSperotti it is an interface, your class must `implement` it, not `extend` it.

Answer (score 0):

This code breaks the string apart and groups into 4 characters before a space is automatically added.

```
EditText ed;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            if (count == 4)
            {
                ed.setText(ed.getText()+" ");
                ed.setSelection(ed.getText().length());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
```

I hope that it helps

Comment: Does not work. Count is always one or zero. I had to manually check _CharSequence s_ length.