# SearchView use multiple comma with numeric keyboard

Tags: java, android, searchview, android-menu, android-inputtype

I'm trying to get my `SearchView` to use multiple comma and numbers.
Unfortunately I'm stuck with be able to use only one comma using the following settings:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER + InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

Another important point is to be able to use the numeric keyboard.

So, basically i would like to write something like `2121,4932,4923`
in the following keyboard:

[image]

Maybe someone has already faced this problem or can just direct me in a relative question

Thanks in advance,
Giacomo.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338445/how-to-automatically-add-thousand-separators-as-number-is-input-in-edittext

Comment: @Kaiser no, it doesn't help :(

Comment: Please attach your full code and explain the problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val searchView: SearchView = search.actionView as SearchView
val editText = searchView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.search_src_text)
editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER + InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
editText.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,")
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, i've adapted your code to java and it's working fine! Thanks <3

Comment: Unfortunately i've found a case that this isn't working if you want to check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212695/setkeylistener-will-override-setinputtype-and-change-the-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to override the [OnKeyDown()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) listener and filter the input there. You may find this link usefull: [example code for OnKeyDown() listener](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/example-code-for-onkeydown-listener-in.html)