# How to add group separator in android EditText?

Tags: android, user-interface

The user is expected to type 12 characters: 3 groups with 4 characters for each group. I'd like to show groups separated from each other using "-" or another character like this right while editing:

> ABCD-EFGH-IJKL

Is it possible?

Comment: manually you can add what your expected.-use textwatcher() for count the letters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947674/custom-format-edit-text-input-android

Comment: i hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976173/adding-a-dash-in-the-edittext-automatically-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172242/live-editing-of-users-input/37187857#37187857

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.format class and get format you want.

Comment: it's inconvenient to work with it, one have to detect if it's the text or separator on every change like delete