# Using fractions on android editText

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

I'd like an inputType in the edit text that i can input fractional number like this: 2/4 (i want print the "/").
The program is about calculating things and i need to type fractional insted of decimal. Thanks. Sorry my bad english.

Comment: There are way around but please make your question a bit more clear. Do you want to enable the user, to input numbers in this way? Or do you want to show it after result of a calculation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert floats to human-readable fractions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95727/how-to-convert-floats-to-human-readable-fractions)

Comment: I want the two ways. I input a fraction and the output is a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use a string for your input text, then to parse the string to figure out what kind of things the user entered.

When the user has finished their input, you can check the string with something like this:

```
public float testInputString(String testString) {
    boolean goodInput = true;
    float result = 0;
    if (testString.contains("/")) {
        //possible division
        String pieces[] = testString.split("/");
        if (pieces.length != 2) {
            goodInput = false;
        } else {
            try {
                float numerator = Float.parseFloat(pieces[0]);
                float denominator = Float.parseFloat(pieces[1]);
                result = numerator/denominator;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                goodInput = false;
            }
        }
    }  else if (testString.contains(".")) {
        try {
            result = Float.parseFloat(testString);                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            goodInput = false;
        }
    }

    //TODO something here if bad input, maybe an alert or something
    return result;
}
```

Also, you can check while they are typing for valid input if you use a [keylistener like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172392/793607).  You could modify that to allow only numbers . and /.

Answer (score -1):

put this property in xml node of Edittext and use Double notation instead of "/"

```
android:digits="1234567890.-"
```

Comment: he wants to be able to represent fractions