# Set EditText Digits Programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am essentially trying to set the digits value of an EditText programmatically. So far I have:

```
weightInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
weightInput.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
```

Which is fine, but I also want to be able to include a decimal place (.). Any ideas?

Comment: You would probably prefer to use `DialerKeyListener` instead of `DigitsKeyListener `

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Try this:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
/>
```

From Code:

```
weightInput.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));
```

But, it allows the user to include several "."
See [JoeyRA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21603219/2914140)'s answer for real numbers.

Comment: That is fine, but I want to do this programatically. Reason for this is because I want to reuse one layout in multiple situations as this digits is the only variable that changes constantly. Doing it in code is much more effective in my situation.

Comment: Thanks. I actually feel this answer deserves the checkmark because it is specific to what I asked for, but both solutions work.

Comment: @feresr, that's strange, because looking at `TextView` sources:

`// If no input type was specified, we will default to generic text, since we can't tell the IME about the set of digits that was selected.`

Comment: What is the use of `.` after 9?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. THe decimal doesn't show up on the keyboard. Infact, I can specify a subset of the numbers in the getInstance() call, and it still lets me type any number.

Comment: `setKeyListener` will limit the use of only digits (not letters) on software keyboards. On emulator's hardware keyboard works well.

Comment: @MiteshShah it allows for decimal place.

Answer (score 34):

Try this:

```
weightInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);           
weightInput.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,true));
```

---

```
public static DigitsKeyListener getInstance (boolean sign, boolean decimal)
```

Returns a DigitsKeyListener that accepts the digits 0 through 9, plus the minus sign (only at the beginning) and/or decimal point (only one per field) if specified.

This solve the problem about the many '.' in EditText

Comment: Just add a clarification:  editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true)); to enable decimals and negative numbers. editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,true)); to enable only positive decimals numbers. editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,false)); to enable only positive integers.

Comment: Question: if you `setInputType` once and again, won't it override the second one to the first one? I think you should use `weightInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);` but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @RafaelRuizMuñoz of course it will override

Comment: this solution still allows to enter dot before you even start to enter digits

Answer (score 21):

Use `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL`.

Also see: [Input Types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html).

Comment: -1? I surely did not do that. Your solution worked, thank you.

Comment: Seems it's been reverted. Glad to help.

Answer (score 14):

if anyone still finding proper way, note that its `setRawInputType()` not `setInputType()`

```
val digits = "ABCDabcd" // or any characters you want to allow
editText.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(digits) 
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME)
```

Answer (score 4):

For IP address input ( Multiple dots and numbers )

try

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ipBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/ipAddrHint"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Comment: Please note that hexadecimal IP addresses (with parts starting with 0x) are valid too, and domain name can be used instead of IP address.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked as expected. Digits in xml file still allow me to put "," in the input.
Check for it, it's works for me:

`edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);`