# Change android:digits programmatically

Tags: android, layout, keyboard

I have this in the layout xml

```
android:digits="0123456789."
android:inputType="phone" />
```

What I want is to be able to change it programatically and be able to change it back and forth.
The inputType part is fine with

```
manual_ip.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

or

```
manual_ip.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

But I'm clueless with digits parts..
I need to limit the chars to "0123456789." or allow everything depending on a checkbox state.

Comment: checkout this link for working answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65073302/6086086

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding

```
manual_ip.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));
```

after

```
manual_ip.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

and nothing after

```
manual_ip.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

solves my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) as :

```
    InputFilter[] digitsfilters = new InputFilter[1];
    digitsfilters[0] = new InputFilter(){

    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (end > start) {

            char[] acceptedChars = new char[]{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

            for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {
                if (!new String(acceptedChars).contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(index)))) {
                return "";
                }
            }
        }
                return null;
    }
};
manual_ip= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.manual_ip);
manual_ip.setFilters(digitsfilters);
```

Comment: This should be accepted as best answer because you can perform a custom filter as you want! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: if i set phone inputType is filters non digits and change nothing. keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("012...") is correct way to overload android:digits operator programatically using setFilters adds I think additional filters and doesn't change inputType default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

just write down this.

```
myEditText.setFilters( new InputFilter[] {
    new PasswordCharFilter(), new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20)});
```

OR

```
TextView editEntryVew = new TextView(...);
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8);
editEntryView.setFilters(FilterArray);
```