# How to use an editText only for numbers

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I wanted to use an editText with the type number.
If you use this, it doesn´t work:

```
    Number editText = (Number) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

The error is at

> Number editText = **(Number) v.findViewById(R.id.editText)**;

It says:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast `android.view.View` to
>   `java.lang.Number`

The solution is easy (thanks to @Ehsan for the helpful answer):

> Edittext editText = (Edittext) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type in XML is `EditText` not `Number` so use `Editext` as

```
EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

For Number use [`inputType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType)

```
android:inputType="number"
```

e.g

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

You can also use [`android:digits`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7300516/4936904) to use specific digit(s)

Answer (score 3):

You are casting your `Edittext` to a `Number`

```
Number editText = (Number) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Replace it with:

```
Edittext editText = (Edittext) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```