# How can divide a amount on triads in input mode?

Tags: android

I need to divide a amount on triads when I input its in EditText, how in calculator. Is there a property EditText or I need do this programmatically?

Example: 
I have: 1000000
I need: 1 000 000
Dividing should occur during the input amount.

Comment: provide some example at least!

Comment: I added example in my question.

Comment: why 1000000 is not divide to 100 000 0 ? if you want to set comma like real number (in realtime) you must know the value first

Comment: AsfK, I'm talking about a triad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Decimal formatting. As Described by [Andreas_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105224/andreas-d) in

[How to set thousands separator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java)

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
System.out.println(formatter.format(bd.longValue()));
```

Comment: QAMAR, how to do it in the process of entering numbers?

Comment: or maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790102/format-credit-card-in-edit-text-in-android