# android edittext textwatcher format phone number like xxx-xxx-xx-xx

Tags: java, android

how to format phone number like **xxx-xxx-xx-xx** using **textwacher**
tried following code,bt its not working while i delete elements

```
 et_phone_num.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());


        et_phone_num.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                et_phone_num.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        MyLog.e("onkeychange","key "+keyCode);
                        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                            keyDel = 1;
                            MyLog.e("onkeychange","key 1");
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if (keyDel == 0) {
                    MyLog.e("onkeychange", "if key 0");
                    int len = et_phone_num.getText().toString().length();
                    if (len == 3) {
                        et_phone_num.setText(et_phone_num.getText().toString() + "-");
                        et_phone_num.setSelection(et_phone_num.getText().toString().length());
                    } else if (len == 7) {
                        et_phone_num.setText(et_phone_num.getText().toString() + "-");
                        et_phone_num.setSelection(et_phone_num.getText().toString().length());
                    } else if (len == 10) {
                        et_phone_num.setText(et_phone_num.getText().toString() + "-");
                        et_phone_num.setSelection(et_phone_num.getText().toString().length());
                    }


                } else {
                    MyLog.e("onkeychange", "else key 0");
                    keyDel = 0;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

finally i did it like this :

```
public class PhoneNumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private static final String TAG = PhoneNumberTextWatcher.class
        .getSimpleName();
private EditText edTxt;
private boolean isDelete;

public PhoneNumberTextWatcher(EditText edTxtPhone) {
    this.edTxt = edTxtPhone;
    edTxt.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                isDelete = true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (isDelete) {
        isDelete = false;
        return;
    }
    String val = s.toString();
    String a = "";
    String b = "";
    String c = "";
    if (val != null && val.length() > 0) {
        val = val.replace("-", "");
        if (val.length() >= 3) {
            a = val.substring(0, 3);
        } else if (val.length() < 3) {
            a = val.substring(0, val.length());
        }
        if (val.length() >= 6) {
            b = val.substring(3, 6);
            c = val.substring(6, val.length());
        } else if (val.length() > 3 && val.length() < 6) {
            b = val.substring(3, val.length());
        }
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (a != null && a.length() > 0) {
            stringBuffer.append(a);
            if (a.length() == 3) {
                stringBuffer.append("-");
            }
        }
        if (b != null && b.length() > 0) {
            stringBuffer.append(b);
            if (b.length() == 3) {
                stringBuffer.append("-");
            }
        }
        if (c != null && c.length() > 0) {
            stringBuffer.append(c);
        }
        edTxt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        edTxt.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
        edTxt.setSelection(edTxt.getText().toString().length());
        edTxt.addTextChangedListener(this);
    } else {
        edTxt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        edTxt.setText("");
        edTxt.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

}
 }
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
et_phone_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_phone_num);
 et_phone_num.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberTextWatcher(et_phone_num));
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/et_phone_num"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:background="@drawable/phone_edittext_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="5XX-XXX-XXXX"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:textColor="@color/cc" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Masked-EditText](https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-EditText) library.

Just pass your mask like below.

```
<com.github.pinball83.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:mask="xxx-xxx-xx-xx"
    app:notMaskedSymbol="x"
    app:maskIconColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

**Note** : If you want to remove incorrect number than place your cursor before that digit and enter your right digit this Masked-EditText library will change it.

Comment: i want to format phone number like xxx-xxx-xx-xx using textwacher

Comment: @DhanrajNaik check edit it will work as per your requirement.

Comment: how to remove middle character with the library if user input wrong character

Comment: i am getting following error and app hangs
"SpellCheckerSession: Failed to get suggestions android.os.DeadObjectException"

Comment: @DhanrajNaik check edit i have changed library in answer.

Comment: Patil  if i delete random character,it is not getting inserted .can you check it please

Comment: @DhanrajNaik suppose number is 123-456-78-90. if you want to change 4 number to 8 than set cursor before 4 number and type 8 number it will change. dont use backspace to change or remove number.