# EditText custom format while enter data android

Tags: android, android-edittext, format, android-inputtype

I am trying to customise the inpout format in EditText.

Following are the format that user can enter.

**If Weight -> ###.##** (Eg 105.50 kg)

**If Water -> ##.##** (Eg 41.50 Ltrs)

Can't guess how to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036794/android-edittext-textwatcher-format-phone-number-like-xxx-xxx-xx-xx

Comment: Do you want to force the user to enter this format or do you want to validate if format is this

Comment: which format do you want

Comment: I wanted to force user to enter this format

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the attribute `inputType="numberDecimal"` for EditText in your layout.xml file?

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) for how to restrict soft keypad for certain type in EditText.