# Android EditText InputType, numeric keyboard + append text

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-inputtype

I have this EditText where the user enter a credit card number. I add a blank space every 4 characters by appending to the EditText like so:

`cardNumberEditText.append(" ");`

I only want to show the numeric keyboard. Therefore I add this attribute to my EditText in XML:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

However this doesn't allow me to append anything to the EditText apart from numbers.

I could change the XML attribute to:

```
android:inputType="number|text"
```

but this would change the keyboard layout thus allowing the user to also enter text which I don't want.

The "add new payment method" in the Play Store app does what I'm after but I just can't figure out how they do it.

Comment: try [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21679833/2900127) or [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: Try using android:digit="0123456789 _" in conjunction with android:inputType="number".

Answer (score 3):

When you use `inputType="number"` it disables `" "` and `"-"` chars.
You can keep using this type and specify that the `" "` char should be counted as a digit by specifying `digits="0123456789 "` in the layout xml as well.