# How do I get tiny spaces as separator of numbers in Android?

Tags: java, android, textview, number-formatting, android-textinputlayout

To make it easier for the user to know the exact score I want to separate blocks of three of my numbers with tiny spaces (Unicode: SIX-PER-EM SPACE).

**Instead of 1241234 I want 1 241 234.**

I tried

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("# ### ### ### ###");
String score = formatter.format(getHighscore());
```

Unfortunately, that code gives me an error. How do I get my six-per-em spaces into my numbers?

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pairs.pairs, PID: 4296
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pairs.pairs/com.pairs.phoneme.TestingActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1469)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5695)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:406)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2190)
                                                                       at com.pairs.phoneme.TestingActivity.portraitLayout(TestingActivity.java:125)
                                                                       at com.pairs.phoneme.TestingActivity.onCreate(TestingActivity.java:76)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1469) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5695) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749) 
                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:406) 
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2190) 
                                                                       at com.pairs.phoneme.TestingActivity.portraitLayout(TestingActivity.java:125) 
                                                                       at com.pairs.phoneme.TestingActivity.onCreate(TestingActivity.java:76) 
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270) 
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1469) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5695) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749) 
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: # ### ### ### ###
                                                                       at java.text.DecimalFormat.initNative(DecimalFormat.java:564)
                                                                       at java.text.DecimalFormat.<init>(DecimalFormat.java:557)
                                                                       at java.text.DecimalFormat.<init>(DecimalFormat.java:535)
                                                                       at com.pairs.phoneme.Score.getHighScoreString(Score.java:103)
                                                                       at com.pairs.phoneme.fragments.ScoreAndTimeFragment.updateTopbarViews(ScoreAndTimeFragment.java:44)
                                                                       at com.pairs.phoneme.fragments.ScoreAndTimeFragment.onCreateView(ScoreAndTimeFragment.java:59)
                                                                       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2236)
                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:954)
                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1131)
                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1233)
                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2228)
                                                                       at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5579)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:406) 
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2190) 
                                                                       at com.pairs.phoneme.TestingActivity.portraitLayout(TestingActivity.java:125) 
                                                                       at com.pairs.phoneme.TestingActivity.onCreate(TestingActivity.java:76) 
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270) 
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1469) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5695) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Comment: What error your code gives?

Comment: @H. Pauwelyn I copy pasted the error. Do you know how I can change the formatting, that it doesn't take that much space?

Comment: there is an inflate exception in your crash logs . Can you post related xml

Comment: @Christian what about a java approach of adding spaces? you don't do that because they are not tiny ? otherwise that's the easiest way

Comment: @VivekMishra : It's not easy to minimalize the xml and given that a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException is thrown I don't think it's at fault.

Comment: @Christian If i do that since i am lazy i count 3 chars from the and add a space again..till the end of the number and reformat my String and set that one! What about that?

Comment: @Christian maybe I'm lack of knowledge but you could use this pattern `###.###` with dots and then replace dots with empty string. Or use `DecimalFormatSymbols` and `setGroupingSeparator();`

Comment: I think this link can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790102/format-credit-card-in-edit-text-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are receiving an exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: # ### ### ### ### at
>   java.text.DecimalFormat.initNative(DecimalFormat.java:564)

I think that is not possible to pass spaces to this constructor.

I have a differente code that do what you need:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);

DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('\u2008');

formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

Log.e("Formatted: ", formatter.format(1241234));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this it should work

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###,###");
String score = formatter.format(getHighscore()).replaceAll(",", " ");
```